# An empty usb drive -- "no permissions for creating a folder or file"

Tags: 14.04, usb, usb-drive

I have a usb drive with **ext4** file system. It is empty. I can't create any files or folders because of the error displayed: "you have no permissions".

Comment: It's likely mounted with root access only.

Comment: @Daniel, how to fix it?

Comment: See the question I linked to above.

Comment: Mind that [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34066/mounting-filesystem-with-special-user-id-set) contains the correct answer to your question, as you're using ext4. The other linked duplicates work only for NTFS / FAT32.