# Use a ext4 USB stick as "normal" pendrive

Tags: usb-drive, chmod, drive, chown

My goal is to have a USB drive in ext4 and to use it as a normal Fat32/NTFS pendrive (or usb box  drive). I would be happy to forget NTFS and Fat32 and to use this USB Drive with all pc in my local net. By the use of CHMOD and CHOWN I would create a REALLY everyone drive in ext4. Every mountpoint should be for everyone. Tons of command line rows are written but no tutorial and simple procedures to make it possible. Thanks.

Comment: You can use `ext4` on your pendrive. The only problem is that only linux systems will be able to see it. But it really makes no sense to use a fs with a journal on a pen drive. You can have e.g. `ext2`.

Comment: And what is the question? Go ahead and use whatever filesystem on your pen drive.

Comment: Forget Windows is my primary goal. This is written in the question. Is is possible with ext4? I suppouse not. I want only a network with linux in my company! I don't want to use NTFS and Fat32. I know that Windows neddds to have an app to read ext4.

Comment: "But it really makes no sense to use a fs with a journal on a pen drive." Read please I wrote: "or USB box". It means 2TB hard drive in the box! Can I use in my network ONLY linux and ONLY extx partitions without NTFS and FAT32? I want to take away a 2TB at home and read it with my Ubuntu Laptop.

Comment: It IS possible to use ext4 on a pen drive, why not? Just format it to ext4. Notheing else to be done.

Comment: What is "USB Box"?

Comment: No Pilot6, Gparted writes the owner's UID number and the group's GID number. If I make the partition with Root for Gparted, after five minutes I reconnect the USB drive the normal user will not use it!! I need chown help. I need chmod help! Then If I take the 2TB drive away I have to reset all again!!

Comment: Pilot! USB box enclosure with drive inside! You can insert hard drive into it, this question is for all mass storage devices!

Comment: If you simply format a partition to `ext4`, it won't have restrictions on it. You can always mount it on any other system.

Comment: You can use `chown` and `chmod` at the file-system's level / the mountpoint, or at the directory level or the file level (specific for individual files if you wish). Do you need help with those commands? I suggest that you use them with `sudo` until you have the desired ownership and permissions to get the access that you want to directories and files.

Comment: First you should check very carefully the actual path to the mountpoint of your ext file system in the USB drive.Then I suggest that you try this command line, which will give full access for 'everybody' to 'everything' in that file system, `sudo chmod -R ugo+rwx /path/to/mountpoint`

Answer (score 2):

If you want an owner/group-agnostic file system for your drive, `ext3`/`ext4` is not the right one for you.

> Only filesystems which do not support Linux permissions like fat have an attribute for ownership/groupship: uid=value and gid=value. See the [manual page on mount](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/en/man8/mount.8.html). ([via](https://askubuntu.com/a/34068/631600))

As a workaround you could use a bind mount if you have `sudo`, but that is probably not what you want:

```
sudo bindfs -u $(id -u) -g $(id -g) /media/diskFoo ~/myUIDdiskFoo
```

([via](https://askubuntu.com/a/353759/631600))

I don't know of any suitable unix/linux/opensource permission-agnostic file system. Unfortunately, you should probably use `exFat` (`NTFS` is a journalling fs and thus not suitable for flash storage).

---

Update: I just read about [F2FS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F2FS) - "Flash Friendly File System", but I don't have any experience with it and it seems to have a normal [unix permission model](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323155/does-f2fs-support-permissions-and-symlinks).

Comment: LINUX only linux, I want to forget windows in my mind. I use linux in all my infrastructure. The Askubuntu is full of expanded command lines, this is a simple question that demonstrates how the linux world is made too mutch complicated. The answer you offered is near the truth!

Answer (score 0):

A solution that gives default permissions to all, also for newly created files, is with a default access control list.

It is described for full in [this unix.stackexchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/422687/133286) -- the short parts:

> ```
> mkfs.ext4 /dev/<device>
> tune2fs -o acl /dev/<device>
> mount /dev/<device> /mnt/<mountpoint>
> chown <username>:<groupname> /mnt/<mountpoint> # Optional; try to use the name of the user who is most commonly using this filesystem
> chmod 777 /mnt/<mountpoint>
> setfacl -m d:u::rwx,d:g::rwx,d:o::rwx /mnt/<mountpoint>
> umount /mnt/<mountpoint>
> ```

Problems might occur if you copy files with their set attributes; permissions might be preserved and other users might not edit or overwrite the files (but usually still read). But since the upper level directories are world-writeable, any user can rename or delete the files (and thus (via copying) also create new files owned by oneself and set permissions to `777`). See the [above mentioned stackexchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/422687/133286).